# «Заметила, что(,) чем ближе, тем…» Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

**Я заметила, что(,) чем ближе я приближалась к дому, тем туманнее становились деревья вокруг.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанная запятая не нужна.

При встрече двух союзов (**что** и **чем**) запятая между ними не ставится, так как дальше в предложении имеется вторая часть двойного союза (**тем**) — изъятие ни одной из придаточных частей невозможно.
(*Я заметила, что тем туманнее становились деревья вокруг* — неправильно.)

[Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140)

*М. Горький утверждал, **что чем** больше он читал, **тем** более книги роднили его с миром, **тем** ярче, значительнее становилась для него жизнь.*

*Я думаю, **что чем** больше человек любит, **тем** сильнее он хочет действовать: любовь, остающуюся только чувством, я никогда не назову подлинной любовью* (В. ван Гог).

Замечу, что использование в предложении (рядом) однокоренных слов ("ближе" и "приближалась") не совсем корректно. Глагол стоит заменить — *подходила, подъезжала, подбиралась, подкрадывалась.*

**Я заметила, что чем ближе я была к дому, тем туманнее становились деревья вокруг.**